# Перерисовка формы C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Программа на C++/CLI разбита на несколько .h файлов.

Есть форма с элементами, по нажатии определенной кнопки - в событии переходит передача управления классу из другого файла.
В нем происходят определенные операции, в следствии которых меняется содержимое формы.

Проблема в том что необходимо пошагово показать изменение формы, а не сразу ее конечное состояние.

Получается что форма перерисовывается только после завершения события, а не многократно на каждой итерации.

Подскажите как вызвать метод Update() у формы, но из другого класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, вы не до конца понимаете принципы [ООП](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), без обид, иначе подобных вопросов не возникало бы наверное.

Для того, что бы вызывать методы класса (обращаться к свойствам), естественно, нужно иметь экземпляр этого класса, за исключением статических методов. 
Идея не совсем удачная. В *другом классе* должна быть ссылка на существующий *объект форму*.
Например. Есть класс, у него есть поле - указатель на форму. В класс, при создании передаете указатель на вашу форму. В методах класса делаете с формой, что хотите.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1(this);
            class1.Method1();
            class1 = null;
        }
    }  
}
```

**Class1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
        private Form1 myForm;
        public Class1(Form1 form1)
        {
            this.myForm = form1;
        }
        public void Method1()
        {
            myForm.Text = "Method1";
            myForm.Update();
            // действия...
            myForm.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Пока метод вашего класса выполняется, все это время окно формы не будет откликаться на любые события и недоступна для пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо, за объяснение! Поучу еще теорию. Но проблему я решил, может глупо, но все же, у меня результат погрешности на каждой итерации выводился в метку Label, в метод другого класса я подавал указатель на нее, а чтобы ее значение перерисовывалось каждый раз просто в событие TextChanged прописал this->Update().